# Angular ng-repeat is not displaying data correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angular and Firebase.

Using the following Data:

```
ticket
|
|
-->uniqueidkjlkjaksjdlkfjasdf
        |
        |
        -->ticket
        |     |
        |     |---> completed:   false
        |     |---> description: asdf
        |     
        --->username: asdf
```

HTML:

```
<div id="logDiv">
            <div ng-repeat="(key,username) in dblogs">
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <li><label>Username:{{username}}</label>                        
                        <button class="destroy" ng-click="removeLog(key)">
                            X</button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am getting this on the page:

```
Username:{"ticket":{"completed":false,"description":"asdf"},"username":"asdf"}
```

How do we format the data correctly?

Comment: What is "dblogs" exactly?
From your results, I'd expect dblogs to be "uniqueidkjlkjaksjdlkfjasdf".
This would cause the ng-repeat to show its data (ticket and username).
It could be helpful if you show the structure of dblogs so we could comment on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="logDiv">
    <div ng-repeat="(key,user) in dblogs">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
             <li><label>Username:{{user.username}}</label>                        
                 <button class="destroy" ng-click="removeLog(key)">
                  X</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wonderful! I'm glad it was this easy.  Thanks!